# Exporting Google spreadsheet to JSON (or XML) format using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to export google spreadsheet to JSON (or XML) using Google Apps script. Here is my google sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15fwOeR6Jo4UadzOTlryTucgI3ZFZ5IVM16GDSwA0XE0/edit?usp=sharing

and here is my google apps script code:

```
function doGet() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15fwOeR6Jo4UadzOTlryTucgI3ZFZ5IVM16GDSwA0XE0/edit#gid=0');
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
 var title = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1:A3").getValues();
 var link = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("B1:B3").getValues();
 return ContentService.createTextOutput(title).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.XML);  
}
```

However, I'm not getting any JSON when I deploy it.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of JSON, you can be got it by changing return part above script to following code.

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(title)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```